# Assignment referring to wrong object

Tags: c#, monogame, assign

I'm making a game using [monogame](/questions/tagged/monogame) and trying to use a controller manager to manage user input.

I've created a class `ControllerManager` to do this. Because I'm trying to take input from 2 controllers, I create three instances of `ControllerManager`: `controllerManager`, `controller1Manager` and `controller2Manager`.

Now, in my player object I have a local variable, `localManager` to which I need to assign to either `controller1Manager` or `controller2Manager` depending on which player it is.

I've been trying to assign it like:

```
this.localManager = Controller1Manager;
```

This results in the `localManager` variable being set to `controllerManager`.

So does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I have no idea other than maybe it has something to do with pointers/references/singleton but I've checked the component list and each individual manager is in there.

Edit:
As requested, here are the constructor, class creation and where I'm trying to change values

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using GDApp;

namespace GDLibrary
{
public class ControllerManager : GameComponent, IService
{
    public GamePadState newState, oldState;
    public PlayerIndex player;

    public ControllerManager(Main game, PlayerIndex index)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.player = index;
    }
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        oldState = newState;
        newState = GamePad.GetState(player);
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public bool IsFirstButtonPress(Buttons button)
    {
        if (oldState.IsButtonUp(button) && newState.IsButtonDown(button))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public bool IsButtonDown(Buttons button)
    {
        return newState.IsButtonDown(button);
    }

    public bool IsButtonUp(Buttons button)
    {
        return newState.IsButtonUp(button);
    }

    #region Thumbsticks

    //Right

    //Magnitude of right stick in right direction
    public float RightStickRight()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Right.X <= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return newState.ThumbSticks.Right.X;
    }

    //Magnitude of right stick in left direction
    public float RightStickLeft()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Right.X >= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return System.Math.Abs(newState.ThumbSticks.Right.X);
    }

    //Magnitude of right stick in upward direction
    public float RightStickUp()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y >= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return System.Math.Abs(newState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y);
    }

    //Magnitude or right stick in downward direction
    public float RightStickDown()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y <= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return newState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y;
    }


    //Left

    //Magnitude of left stick in right direction
    public float LeftStickRight()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Left.X <= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return newState.ThumbSticks.Left.X;
    }

    //Magnitude of left stick in left direction
    public float LeftStickLeft()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Left.X >= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return System.Math.Abs(newState.ThumbSticks.Left.X);
    }

    //Magnitude of left stick in upward direction
    public float LeftStickUp()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y >= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return System.Math.Abs(newState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y);
    }

    //Magnitude or right stick in downward direction
    public float LeftStickDown()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y <= 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return newState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y;
    }

    #endregion

    public bool RightStickCentered()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Right.X.Equals(0) && newState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y.Equals(0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool LeftStickCentered()
    {
        if (newState.ThumbSticks.Left.X.Equals(0) && newState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y.Equals(0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Vector2 RightStick()
    {
        return this.newState.ThumbSticks.Right;
    }

    public Vector2 LeftStick()
    {
        return this.newState.ThumbSticks.Left;
    }

    public bool LeftStickMoved()
    {
        if (!oldState.ThumbSticks.Left.X.Equals(newState.ThumbSticks.Left.X) || !oldState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y.Equals(newState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool RightStickMoved()
    {
        if (!oldState.ThumbSticks.Right.X.Equals(newState.ThumbSticks.Right.X) || !oldState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y.Equals(newState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Creating managers:

```
this.controller1Manager = new ControllerManager(this, PlayerIndex.One);
Components.Add(controller1Manager);
IServiceContainer.AddService(typeof(ControllerManager), controller1Manager);

this.controller2Manager = new ControllerManager(this, PlayerIndex.Two);
Components.Add(controller2Manager);
IServiceContainer.AddService(typeof(ControllerManager), controller2Manager);
```

Changing values:

```
if (this.index.Equals(PlayerIndex.One))
    {
        this.localManager = Controller1Manager;
    }
else if (this.index.Equals(PlayerIndex.Two))
    {
        this.localManager = Controller2Manager;
        Controller2Manager.player = index;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `Controller1Manager` wasn't assigned to `ControllerManager` previously to that?

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted is processed? Better if you post the whole code.

Comment: It seems to be assigned to ControllerManager as soon as it's instantiated. Using the following:

    this.controller1Manager = new ControllerManager(this, PlayerIndex.One);
    System.Console.WriteLine("I have been assigned " + controller1Manager);

prints GDLibrary.ControllerManager

Comment: I believe so, I've been using Console.WriteLine to test values so I can see when it gets assigned from null to the wrong value. @LPs Would you like to see the whole class or just the constructor?

Comment: Your `WriteLine` in your comment when you write out `controller1Manager` is just writing out the type of the variable.  Does the `ControllerManager` class override the `ToString` method?  Can you write out the value of some specific property of the controller manager to confirm which objects are which?  For example, can you write out something like `Console.WriteLine(controller1Manager.ID)` (assuming ID is a valid property)?

Comment: Thanks @Chris, hadn't caught that. Having gone through again looking at the player index (should be different per manager) it seems that setting the player value for controller1Manager also changed the value for controller2Manager
Edit: setting the player variable for one ControllerManager actually sets it for all instances of the class.

Comment: I think that is important to see your constructor and classes creation to understand deeply your problem. A snapshot of code where you change values of ControllerManager class.

Comment: @LPs That code has been added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by passing a ControllerManager into the PlayerObject in place of a PlayerIndex. The reason all of the controllerManagers seemed to have their variables changed at once was their inclusion in the IServiceContainer shown in the edits above. IServiceContainer stores only one instance of a given type (It's a Dictionary) so only the most recent addition was being saved.